Google Earth Engine with Continuous Change Detection and Classification (CCDC)
I’m working with a script from the Google Earth Engine tutorial on Interpreting Time Series with CCDC. Based on the original script, I want to modify it to extract only the negative magnitude values from the time series data. Then, I need to find the maximum absolute value among those negative values.
However, when I run the modified script, I encounter the error: Max Negative Magnitude: Layer error: Image.arrayArgmax: Expected array type. Here’s the current version of my script:
var magnitudes = ccdResults.select('SWIR1_magnitude').arrayMask(mask).arrayPad([1]); 
// Get index of max abs magnitude of change. 
var maxIndex = magnitudes.abs().arrayArgmax().arrayFlatten([['index']]); 
// Select max magnitude and its timing 
var selectedMag = magnitudes.arrayGet(maxIndex); 
var selectedTbreak = dates.arrayGet(maxIndex).selfMask();     
var magVisParams = {palette: palettes.matplotlib.viridis[7], min: -0.15, max: 0.15}; 

Map.addLayer(selectedMag, magVisParams, 'Max mag'); 
Map.addLayer(selectedTbreak, timeVisParams, 'Time of max mag');

The full link of my script is https://code.earthengine.google.com/bef5f0e9b1b1dbc69e6c5c5d558dbb3b
Please help me to fix this.

You problems is this:
var flattenedMagnitudes = magnitudes.arrayFlatten([['magnitude']])

Here, magnitudes include more than one array element. After all, that's the whole point, you are searching for the max negative magnitude. To sort this out, simply don't try to flatten the array. When masking out non-negative magnitude, you'll also have to use arrayMask() instead of updateMask().
var negativeMask = magnitudes.lt(0);
var negativeMagnitudes = magnitudes.arrayMask(negativeMask);

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a43aae9a1e7c7f53d86e2266d1bdaee9
In general, when you get an error, the error often isn't in the line where it was triggered. Try to go backwards from your error and output intermediate values to find the actual cause.

Thank you . It worked well with your suggestion:-)
